# what is fastest way to remove elements from array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am removing an object from an array and came to know different methods mention below:

let this is my array:

```
var user = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}, {id:4}];
```

First method using splice:

```
let index = user.findIndex(e=>{
    return e.id == 3;
});
array.splice(index, 1);
```

Second method using filter:

```
array = array.filter((data)=>{
   return data.id !== 3;
});
```

Third method using third party library(like lodash):

```
_.remove(array, function(data) {
    return data.id == 3 ;
});
```

which is the fastest among these or is there any more efficient way in terms of performance to remove specific element(which is an object).

Comment: [Have you tried them in your application?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @VLAZ, yes tried all seems to same because data size is low. and all are near 1 to 3 milisecond

Comment: In that case, the performance difference is negligible. Choose whichever you wish and there wouldn't be much of a difference.

Comment: Not entirely sure about the context of this application, but microoptimizations like these usually are not the bottleneck when it comes to performance.

Comment: sure,   i will be checking for lagre data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the execution time of each of options mentioned, you can use -

```
console.time("Time");
// place your options one by one in between
console.timeEnd("Time");
```

This will really help with analyzing performance of each piece of code.

Comment: yes tried all seems to same because data size is low. and all are near 1 to 3 milisecond.

Comment: Then kindly increase the data size to a significant amount then probably you will have the answer. Testing options in isolation will definitely differ when tested in the application level. As all are workable solution but performance really depends upon the usage as well :)